# SVNADMIN: lslocks and rmlocks disagree

Tags: svn

When I run the command: `svnadmin lslocks My_Repo| grep -B2 user_name`, I get about 10 files which are locked. Other people see that this user has them locked in TortoiseSVN.  When I run `svnadmin rmlocks My_Repo` on these locked files I get a message that "it isn't locked".

Comment: This is happening with one specific user who claims they have had strange locks showing up in their name ever since they had a crash while in a working copy on their desktop.  I am not sure what the server is confused about though, why does lslocks show locks and rmlocks see no locks?

Comment: what does the user actually see?

Comment: The user sees "file is already locked by <username>", exactly what you would see if the file or directory is actually locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this one wasn't hard after all.  If the Path has spaces in it, svnadmin rmlocks will consider that to be a different argument delimited by a white space!  I got around this issue by using: `svnadmin lslocks Software |grep Path|sed -e 's/\(^Path: \)\(\/.*\)/\2/' -e 's/ /\\&/'|while read my_path;do svnadmin rmlocks Software "$my_path";done`